# Cannot download react web page

Tags: reactjs, curl, react-router

I have a react web page `localhost:8080/details/1`. When I try `curl localhost:8080/details/1`, only `index.html` page gets downloaded. How can I download the specific page?

Thanks,

Comment: You probably need to implement [server side rendering](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md)

Comment: This because curl wont execute javascript in the page.